# Handle a ternary relationship using Javax annotation and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ternary

I'm making an application that use a Rest Api to handle the communication between front and database.

Spring is used for the Java Api and Postgres as database.

The point is that I need a ternary relationship between three table. I explain myself, I have three table :
 - user
 - role
 - project

Every user have a specific role depending on the project.
When I select a Project (in front), I need to display all the participants with their respective project.
Those are my classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    private String image;


@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private Long version;

    @NotNull
    private Date date;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_profile_project", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<User> participants;

@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<Permission>(0);

    public Profile(){}

    public Profile(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Profile(String name, Set<Permission> permissions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Comment: Can users be associated with more than one role in one project? Can a user be associated with more than on project? Need to know the relationship types before we can help

Comment: Yes, so what is your question?

Comment: Every user is associated with one role for one project. Each user can have many projects.
The point is that some user could have access to different functions depending on their roles on the project.

I need to get the role by calling an url like localhost:8080/userID/projectId